# How to get id from the directive template and pass in function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to get id from a template's function, but i am unable to get it. without arguments i can easily call a function but with arguments i dont know how to do this. So far this is what i did.

**Directive Template (Job search Html)**

```
<div class="artist-job-search-filters">
                    <div class="foo" ng-click="$ctrl.changeArtistJobFilter(1)" ng-class="$ctrl.searchFilterAll ? 'artist-filter-selected' : 'artist-filter'">All</div>
                    <div class="foo" ng-click="$ctrl.changeArtistJobFilter(2)" ng-class="$ctrl.searchFilterJob ? 'artist-filter-selected' : 'artist-filter'">Job</div>
                    <div class="foo" ng-click="$ctrl.changeArtistJobFilter(3)" ng-class="$ctrl.searchFilterStandBy ? 'artist-filter-selected' : 'artist-filter'">Standby</div>
                    <div class="foo" ng-click="$ctrl.changeArtistJobFilter(4)" ng-class="$ctrl.searchFilterAudition ? 'artist-filter-selected' : 'artist-filter'">Audition</div>
                    <div class="foo" ng-click="$ctrl.changeArtistJobFilter(5)" ng-class="$ctrl.searchFilterApplied ? 'artist-filter-selected' : 'artist-filter'">Applied</div>
                </div>
```

Here `changeArtistJobFilter`is my function and i am passing values. Below is my `directive.js`

**Directive.js**

```
app.directive('jobsSearch', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        'artistSearchModel': "=",
        'showDropdown': "=",
        'operaticRoleSearchResult' : "=",
        'viewAllJobs' : "&",
        'musicalWorkSearchResult' : "=",
        'institutionSearchResult' : "=",
        'changeArtistJobFilter' : "&",
        'searchFilterAll' : "=",
        'searchFilterJob' : "=",
        'searchFilterStandBy' : "=",
        'searchFilterAudition' : "=",
        'searchFilterApplied' : "=",
        'searchArtistJob': "&"
    },
    controller: function () { },
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: '/views/profile/directives/job_search.html'
};
```

});

And here is the view from where i am calling the directive.

**View Html with directive**

```
<jobs-search artist-search-model="jobDashboard.artistSearchModel" 
          search-artist-job="jobDashboard.searchArtistJob()"
          show-dropdown="jobDashboard.showDropdown"
          operatic-roleSearch-result="jobDashboard.operaticRoleSearchResult"
          view-all-jobs="jobDashboard.viewAllJobs()"
          musical-work-search-result="jobDashboard.musicalWorkSearchResult"
          institution-search-result="jobDashboard.institutionSearchResult"
          change-artist-job-filter="jobDashboard.changeArtistJobFilter()"
          search-filter-all="jobDashboard.searchFilterAll"
          search-filter-job="jobDashboard.searchFilterJob"
          search-filter-stand-by="jobDashboard.searchFilterStandBy"
          search-filter-audition="jobDashboard.searchFilterAudition"
          search-filter-applied="jobDashboard.searchFilterApplied"
          ></jobs-search>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put an argument inside function from where you calling the directive

```
change-artist-job-filter="jobDashboard.changeArtistJobFilter(**filter**)"
```